# Delay one thing in python without delaying anything else

Tags: python, pygame

I want this animation to play with a slight delay inbetween each dripx() command, but I can't delay anything else because the players character is also effected by any sleep/wait commands. (Kinda new to python/pygame so I don't know everything)

```
def wateranimation():
    drip1()
    drip2()
    drip3()
    drip4()
    drip5()
    drip6()
```

Comment: @Alan That is not how you do this in game programming. You use the time since last iteration of the main loop to keep track of timers and such.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1) Store the current state, using a class. Every frame you call a specific function with the number of milliseconds since the last frame, and have it figure out if it needs to do anything this frame.

2) Threaded programming. You create a start a thread that just has the job of running that animation, and spends most of its time asleep.

Comment: The correct answer here is 1. The threaded solution should never be used. You might wanna show an example with pygame.time.Clock and it's tick function. It retruns the time since the last call to tick